# what is the most simple straightford way to deploy html/javascript into service mix

Tags: javascript, html, apache-karaf, karaf

I have a small html/web page I wanted to deploy service mix somehow. 
I have never tried to use any web based with service mix and I wanted see what are the steps you need to this?

I know the web page side and am using service mix but am not sure how to use a simple html / javascript in service mix. It should be a simple process but with service mix I was trying to do some research and I some conflicting ideas.

Just want to know the exact steps for deploying web based html/javacript to service mix. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a look into the docs:

http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/5.x/users-guide/web-applications.html

Comment: I want to know how to deploy not as a war but as just a jar file